# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to create keystore

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded an android studio project from Github. Whenever I try to import and run this on my android studio with Genymotion emulator, I get this error. Why I am getting this?        .

> Error : Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug' com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to create keystore.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415156/unable-to-recreate-missing-debug-keystore maybe a permission issue?

Comment: no. I always run Android Studio with "run as adminstrator" & enabling instant run solved this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. I enabled Instant run and it worked for me. Reason might be a code issue.